# java 8 List<Object[]> to Map<String, Map<String, BigDecimal>>

Tags: java

The list contains Arrays of (`String`,`String`,`BigDecimal`).
I want to convert the `List`  to `Map<String, Map<String, BigDecimal>>`
grouped by the first String using java 8 Stream class.

```
List<Object[]> list = ss.createCriteria(PayrollDeduction.class)
                .createAlias("payroll", "pay")
                .add(Restrictions.le("pay.paymentDate", atDate))
                .createAlias("payroll.employee", "employee")
                .add(Restrictions.in("employee.id", Arrays.asList(empId)))
                .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                        .add(Projections.property("gouvAgencyCode"))
                        .add(Projections.property("code"))
                        .add(Projections.sum("amount"))
                        .add(Projections.groupProperty("gouvAgencyCode"))
                        .add(Projections.groupProperty("code")))
                .setReadOnly(true)
                .list();
                 list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r->r[0], Collectors.mapping(mapper, downstream)));
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you post some code?

Comment: I've tried many ways. all fall down. I don know if it is possible in java 8 stream

Comment: Java is an Object-Oriented language. Use it. Don't use an `Object[]` with three disparate values. Use a class with 3 fields and appropriate getter methods.

Comment: in fact, I have a db query that return list of 3 fields. I just want to transform that list to what I mentioned in my question. I dont want to retrieve all entity fields for performance issue.

Comment: Can you share some data and the result you're trying to get for it? It would make the question easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
List<Object[]> list = Arrays.asList(
        new Object[] { "A", "X", new BigDecimal("1") },
        new Object[] { "A", "Y", new BigDecimal("2.0") },
        new Object[] { "B", "X", new BigDecimal("3.00") },
        new Object[] { "C", "Z", new BigDecimal("4.000") }
);

Map<String, Map<String, BigDecimal>> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> (String) r[0],
                                       Collectors.toMap(r -> (String) r[1],
                                                        r -> (BigDecimal) r[2])));

System.out.println(map);
```

*Output*

```
{A={X=1, Y=2.0}, B={X=3.00}, C={Z=4.000}}
```

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/):

- You seem to be using Hibernate;
- You want to transform the results from your projection into some other format.

Hibernate's own [ResultTransformer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html) could have solved your problem in a cleaner way.